# Is there a __dunder__ method corresponding to |= (pipe equal/update) for dicts in python 3.9?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.9

In python 3.9, dictionaries gained combine `|` and update `|=` operators. Is there a dunder/magic method which will enable this to be used for other classes? I've tried looking in the python source but found it a bit bewildering.

Comment: See [PEP 584](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#id19)

Comment: They're only new *for dictionaries*, the magic methods are documented in the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) already.

Comment: As another extreme example of the dunder name not necessarily indicating what it *does*, consider that `"%s" % "x"` is implemented as `"%s".__mod__("x")`.

Comment: @chepner sure, but it's co-opting a numeric operator where the dunder name is quite descriptive. Plus, "or" and "union" are related in the same way "and" and "intersection" are... I'll give you that `%` for string interpolation is pretty arbitrary...

Comment: I was reading this as the OP thinking there must be a new set of methods to handle `|` and `|=` for `dicts` because it's not a bitwise operation, not that `|` and `|=` are new operators altogether (though that might be the more logical reading).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, `|` and `|=` correspond to [`__or__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__or__) and [`__ior__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__ior__).

Don't look at the *python source code*, look at the documentation. In particular, the data model.

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types)

And note, this isn't specific to python 3.9.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the method for `|` is `__or__` and the method for `|=` is `__ior__`. You can see an (approximate) Python implementation [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0584/#reference-implementation) in PEP 584.

```
def __or__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(other, dict):
        return NotImplemented
    new = dict(self)
    new.update(other)
    return new

def __ior__(self, other):
    dict.update(self, other)
    return self
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to dig through the source. It's clearly documented as `__or__` and `__ior__`. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html is the relevant documentation.